# Import Yii2 validators in angular forms

Tags: angularjs, validation, yii2, client-side-validation

I am developing an application that uses the yii2 framework to handle data models and angularJS for the frontend counterpart. In some views, I need to handle the input fields with angular forms (i.e., I cannot use Yii2 ActiveForms) but, in this way, I cannot take advantage from the client side validators that the yii2 frameworks offers (the ones that are automatically generated by the ActiveRecords rules). Is there a way to get the Yii2 client side validators and attach them to the angular forms? Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. AJAX validators are simply server side validations, if you using REST on backend for your app you will get errors from server in response. Process them on angular side and show, that's it. No need to mix flies with honey.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wrongly wrote AJAX in place of client side validation. What I meant is that I would like to attach the client side validators automatically generated by the Yii2 active records following the model rules to angular fields to keep coherence between the Yii2 rules and the front end validators. I edited the question accordingly